# Handling Uploadify situation when file exisits

Tags: jquery, uploadify

Have a very annoying issue not being able to notify users when they have tried to upload a file which already exists.  When its found that the file exists it does as I wish and does not overwrite however I cant work out how to let the user know somehow.  I have a classic ASP version of the code running.  The upload dialog/progress bar appears then quickly goes away because I have these settings n place:

```
'multi'          : false,
'auto'           : true,
```

I am hoping to do something like this:

```
onDuplicaetDetected:   function () {
                   alert('upload failed because the file is a duplicate')
```

which would give me a JS error prompt.  Or even:

```
'duplicateFound' : function() {
self.location='duplicateDetected.asp?reload=t';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Googling give me this link http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadifive/oncheck/

So, looks like you need the *onCheck* event and your code should then be something like this

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'checkScript'  : '/checkFileExists.asp',
        'uploadScript' : '/upload.asp',
        'onCheck'      : function(file, exists) {
            if (exists) {
                alert('upload failed because the file is a duplicate')^;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: So it looks like I need to create the checkFileExists.asp file and then use the function behind the 'onCheck' line. Unfortunately I have a classic ASP version of the code, all the downloadable code is PHP. I dont know PHP. Although I will be trying to convert it, can I ask for some help? here is the code:    
    $targetFolder = '/uploads';  
    if (file_exists($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) { 
    echo 1; 
    } else { 
    echo 0; 
    }

Comment: Sorry about the post above I am having trouble identifying the code as code so it appears as it should.  Indenting is not working for me :o(

Comment: Hi , take a look here to see how it can help you : http://www.w3schools.com/asp/met_fileexists.asp
You rcode should become something like this (colons can be replaced by new line off course). ***Dim uploadPath : uploadPath = Server.Mappath("/uploads") & "/" & request.form('filename') : 
Dim fs : Set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") :
if fs.FileExists(uploadPath)=true then :
  response.write(1) :
else :
  response.write(0) :
end if : 
Set fs=nothing***

Comment: thank you for the assistance you have been very helpful. I will check this out